# Observable timer: return action after timer finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to create a simple poll worker with a timer from rxjs in the React app.

For this, I have created an epic. Pretty simple - I'm getting from the server some info each 5 sec during 1 min.

```
const processPollEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(POLL_START),
  mergeMap(() => timer(0, 5000).pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => from(service.getSmth()).pipe(map(resp => {
      if (resp.isSuccess) {
        return processPollStop();
      }
      return processPollContinue();
    }))),
    takeUntil(action$.ofType(POLL_STOP)),
    take(12),
  )),
);
```

It's worked fine but I can't solve one corner case.
Now I return POLL_STOP action only when the response from the server is successful.
But when time is over, I do nothing.

Can I return some action when the timer will be finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the inner chain inside `mergeMap`:

```
concat(
  timer(0, 5000).pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => from(service.getSmth()).pipe(map(resp => {
      if (resp.isSuccess) {
        return processPollStop();
      }
      return processPollContinue();
    }))),
    take(12),
  ),
  of(CREATE_OTHER_ACTION_HERE),
).pipe(
  takeUntil(action$.ofType(POLL_STOP)),
)
```

`concat` will subscribe to `of()` only after the previous chain has completed. Then `takeUntil` can still complete the whole chain so `concat` will just unsubscribe from its inner Observable.

Btw, make sure you're importing the correct `concat` from `'rxjs'` and not from `'rxjs/operators'`.